# How to create table body component in react

Tags: reactjs, html-table

I tried to create  table in react. First of all I divided it into 3 components which are TableBody, TableHeader and Table.

This is TableBody and it is not working correctly. Can you fix it?

```
import React from 'react';

function TableBody(props) {

const rowdata=props.data.map((row) => {
   a= row.map((colum) => {
        <td>
            {colum}
        </td>
    })
})
return (
    <tr>
        {rowdata}
    </tr>
);
}
export default TableBody;
```

Comment: you are not returning anything from map callback method, also assign unique value as **key** to each td, write it like this: `const rowdata = props.data.map(row => (
    row.map(colum => (
        <td>
            {colum}
        </td>
    ))
))`

Comment: Thank you  @Mayank Shukla. it is working.